# Detectron2 video object detection

Tags: video, detection, detectron

I run obeject detection code, using detectron2.
I trained the net and it works fine on images.
Now I would like to test it on video, but when I run the video it doesn't detect any of my labels, more then that, it detect untrained object, means my code using some other model path.

```
# Run frame-by-frame inference demo on this video (takes 3-4 minutes)
# Using a model trained
!git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2
!cd detectron2 && python demo/demo.py --video-input ../video-clip.mp4 --confidence-threshold 0.6 -- 
output ../video-output-agripper.mkv
#!cd detectron2 && python demo/demo-test.py --config-file configs/Agripper/agripper.yaml --video- 
input ../video-clip.mp4 --confidence-threshold 0.6 --output ../video-output-agripper.mkv --opts 
MODEL.WEIGHTS configs/Agripper/model_0024999.pth
```

I new in this field so I don't find what line I need to change.
Where I input my trained model?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you go through the following tutorial, you would learn basics about detectron2. It is quite easy to start. Then run the video inference.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16jcaJoc6bCFAQ96jDe2HwtXj7BMD_-m5